# "could not locate configuration or package directory, unable to load configuration file."

Tags: python-3.x

I am using jupyter notebook by anaconda environment. My python version is 3.8.3. Using anaconda prompt I installed a module called `dispersion` typing `pip install dispersion`. It was successfully installed.
Now, I am trying to type `import dispersion as disp` in jupyter. It gives the error: `"could not locate configuration or package directory, unable to load configuration file."`
I also tried "pip3 install dispersion" in prompt. This is the result:

```
*"Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->dispersion) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->dispersion) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->dispersion) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->dispersion) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->dispersion) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->dispersion) (2021.3)"*
```

I think the error is related to the path of the package, but I checked that the "dispersion" module is at least at the same directory with "numpy" which works without any problem.

Can you help me to manage this?
Thanks in advance